# MS Access - how can i aggregate two queries in one recordset?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

My query works in VBA code, but I will have a lot of this kind of queries, so I don't want to create a new "rst" section every time. (recordset).

The code I created is below.

```
Private Sub wpr_krotkaNazwaProjektu_AfterUpdate()
Dim rst4 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst5 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql4 As String
Dim strSql5 As String
Dim krotkaNazwaProjektu4 As String
Dim krotkaNazwaProjektu5 As String


krotkaNazwaProjektu4 = wpr_krotkaNazwaProjektu.Text
krotkaNazwaProjektu5 = wpr_krotkaNazwaProjektu.Text

strSql4 = "SELECT Ewidencje.E_dataRozpoczeciaProjektu from Ewidencje INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu4) & "' "
strSql5 = "SELECT Ewidencje.E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu from Ewidencje INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu5) & "' "

Set rst4 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql4)
Set rst5 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql5)

przypisanie4 = rst4!E_dataRozpoczeciaProjektu
przypisanie5 = rst5!E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu

rst4.Close
Set rst4 = Nothing
rst5.Close
Set rst5 = Nothing

wpr_planowanaDS.Value = przypisanie4
wpr_planowanaDZ.Value = przypisanie5
End Sub
```

I don't want to open "rst" every time, whether such a query can be modified in such a way that it won't create many variables in ten queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly.

Using the next code you should be able to do the same just using one variable for each thing:

```
Private Sub wpr_krotkaNazwaProjektu_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim krotkaNazwaProjektu As String

    krotkaNazwaProjektu = wpr_krotkaNazwaProjektu.Text

    strSql = "SELECT Ewidencje.E_dataRozpoczeciaProjektu from Ewidencje INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & krotkaNazwaProjektu & "' "
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    przypisanie = rst!E_dataRozpoczeciaProjektu
    rst.Close
    wpr_planowanaDS.Value = przypisanie

    strSql = "SELECT Ewidencje.E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu from Ewidencje INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & krotkaNazwaProjektu & "' "
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    przypisanie = rst!E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu
    rst.Close
    wpr_planowanaDZ.Value = przypisanie

    Set rst = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of non-English names makes it impossible to figure out what your data is about but you could try something like this:

```
"SELECT IIF(KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu4) & "',Ewidencje.E_dataRozpoczeciaProjektu,NULL) AS KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu
    IIF(KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu5) & "',Ewidencje.E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu,NULL) AS E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu
FROM Ewidencje
    INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu
WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu4) & "' OR KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu5) & "'"
```

It combines your two queries into one. It can probably be simplified quite a bit if I understood what it is about and which field names are unique between the two linked tables and there may be a quote missing here or there that you may have to troubleshoot.